# What errors are in this transcription in Status Animarum from Slovenia?

Tags: 19th-century, palaeography, austria, german-language, kurrent

I've attempted to transcribe the entry for Mali Cirnik 11 in the Austrian Empire in the first half of the 19<sup>th</sup> century:

[image]

This is written in German using [Kurrent handwriting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurrent) style.

In particular, I wonder about these:

- First Name: Lumsoluior
- Location: grenjak
- Wife's name: Bruzivi Trimjerfu
- Son Franz's birth month: gborm
- Scribbled ink name: Joseph Luyarizh
- Scribbled pencil name: Martin Barthol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Bartelmä Gregorzhizh
- wife: Luzia Perjatu
- Franz' birth month: 9<sup>ber</sup> (November)

I don't have any better suggestion for the place name, perhaps someone with local knowledge can provide more insight on this.

Likewise I hesitate to guess on the signed names at the bottom; however I do not think they read Joseph Luyarizh or Martin Barthol.

In my very limited experience in German palaeography, my favourite resource for German handwriting is the [BYU German script tutorial](https://script.byu.edu/Pages/German/en/alphabet.aspx). When deciphering this handwriting you have to forget what the letters look like in English, and (particularly if unfamiliar with German) take it one letter at a time. I find it helpful to have both the document and a reference alphabet open side by side on my screen.

Comment: I do believe the second, fainter name does read "Martin Barthol[omäus]". There is also a third word, barely legible, that follows these two. I won't even hazard a guess.